# How can I get a linear forecast in BigQuery?

Tags: functions, array, bigquery

BigQuery has no native support for linear forecasting outside of machine learning, but it does support user-defined functions, and these can accept arrays as inputs.  However, (as of 2023/10 anyway), these can only be expressions, not multi-line statements.

Is it possible to calculate a linear regression within these limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, though the limitations of BigQuery make it a bit ugly on the back end.  Calling the method is simple enough:

```
SELECT util.linear_forecast([ 20.0, 28.0, 31.0, 38.0, 40.0 ], [ 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 15.0, 21.0 ], 30.0);
```

Result: 10.6073.

The `linear_forecast` function calls two helpers, to keep the code somewhat readable.  Start with this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.linear_slope(xValues ARRAY<FLOAT64>, yValues ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
    RETURNS FLOAT64 AS
    (
        (
        SELECT
            SUM
                (
                -- For each entry, take the average value of x less the value of x; multiply that by the difference between the average value of y less y
                  ((SELECT AVG(x) FROM UNNEST(xValues) AS x) - x)
                * ((SELECT AVG(y) FROM UNNEST(yValues) AS y) - y)
                )
        FROM
            UNNEST(xValues) AS x WITH OFFSET x_seq
            INNER JOIN UNNEST(yValues) AS y WITH OFFSET y_seq ON x_seq = y_seq
        )
    /
        (
        SELECT
            SUM
                (
                -- For each entry, take the average of x less the value of x; square it
                POWER((SELECT AVG(x) FROM UNNEST(xValues) AS x) - x, 2.0)
                )
        FROM
            UNNEST(xValues) AS x
        )
    );
```

...then this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.linear_intercept(xValues ARRAY<FLOAT64>, yValues ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
    RETURNS FLOAT64 AS
    (
      (SELECT AVG(y) FROM UNNEST(yValues) AS y)
    - (SELECT AVG(x) FROM UNNEST(xValues) AS x) * util.linear_slope(xValues, yValues)
    );
```

...and finally the wrapper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.linear_forecast(xValues ARRAY<FLOAT64>, yValues ARRAY<FLOAT64>, forecastX FLOAT64)
    RETURNS FLOAT64 AS
    (
    util.linear_intercept(xValues, yValues) + util.linear_slope(xValues, yValues) * forecastX
    );
```

Watch the parentheses; they are all needed.